# How to get the wifi password off a school wifi without going up to the router

Tags: wifi

I have an iPad for school and I want to see the password for the wifi so I can put it into my android phone but I'm not able to go up to the router unless I want to get suspended please help.

Comment: Ask your school's IT department for the password. If they won't give it to you, there's probably a very good reason. I'm assuming the iPad your school has provisioned for you connects with the school's wifi automatically.

Answer (score -1):

WiFi passwords are saved to a hidden location on your device and you can't see them as you can do on a computer.